# How signaling in WebRTC works in following scenario?

Tags: webrtc

I read about this online and I come to know that signaling is used for initiation of the communication, But I am very confused about how would I get the `ip:port` combination for the other peer.

I thought of three scenarios.

1. On the same network (LAN)
2. On the internet(but not behind a
   proxy/NAT)
3. On the internet but behind a proxy/NAT

For 1. I get that we can get the `ip:port` from the signaling process it self(if I am not wrong)

For 2. and 3. How would we get the `IP:PORT`, how would STUN/TURN servers and ICE will play their role in all these cases? I know for what reason they are used for but can't figure out how each of them will fit in these scenarios.

Update: The question that is posted in comments is the one which compliments what I assumed that it should work in this way, what I don't know is how TURN would do the update, would it be establishing the communication using SDP? like it did for STUN? Is it absolutely necessary for TURN to work we should deploy it on cloud?

Comment: Are you asking what you as a web developer need to do, or are you wondering how ICE does what it does?

Comment: I am asking about how they work combined manner, I know that during signaling SDP exchange takes place where the route to reach the peer is defined, but what happens in the case when peer is not on same network or behind a NAT, how does webRTC identifies that, I know using STUN/TURN server but how do they coordinate internally ? for example I know during signaling it exchange SDP where the route,network and media information are being shared with the other peer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under which conditions and how does Webrtc PeerConnection work without a TURN server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142486/under-which-conditions-and-how-does-webrtc-peerconnection-work-without-a-turn-se)